# How to change the accelerator key for vim menus?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have `nnoremap <A-h> <C-w><left>`. Unfortunately, this fails because Alt+h is an accelerator key for the help menu, so vim ignores my mapping and opens the menu. Is there anyway to change the accelerator key, ore even disable it, for a menu?

I have looked at the help files, but am sofar unable to find an answer. I am looking for a short piece of vimscript, not a plugin, as I am trying to be sure that I understand all that is put into my file. Intuitively, I think there is probably a way to set the mapping, I just don't know what it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable the menu (`set guioptions-=m`), this will allow you to map the keystroke you want.

Alternatively, `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` is what is sourced to create the menu itself, which also defines what the shortcut keys for the menu would be. You could override the names of the help menu entries to remove the `&` tokens (which define what the shortcut will be).

For example, the `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` I've got installed has this:

```
" Help menu
an 9999.10 &Help.&Overview<Tab><F1> :help<CR>
an 9999.20 &Help.&User\ Manual      :help usr_toc<CR>
an 9999.30 &Help.&How-to\ links     :help how-to<CR>
an <silent> 9999.40 &Help.&Find\.\.\.   :call <SID>Helpfind()<CR>
an 9999.45 &Help.-sep1-         <Nop>
an 9999.50 &Help.&Credits       :help credits<CR>
an 9999.60 &Help.Co&pying       :help copying<CR>
an 9999.70 &Help.&Sponsor/Register  :help sponsor<CR>
an 9999.70 &Help.O&rphans       :help kcc<CR>
an 9999.75 &Help.-sep2-         <Nop>
an 9999.80 &Help.&Version       :version<CR>
an 9999.90 &Help.&About         :intro<CR>
```

You can remove the entire help menu via: `aunmenu &Help` and either leave it out or, if you for some reason use it, re-create it with the `&` in a different spot:

```
" Better Help menu.
aunmenu &Help
an 9999.10 He&lp.&Overview<Tab><F1> :help<CR>
an 9999.20 He&lp.&User\ Manual      :help usr_toc<CR>
an 9999.30 He&lp.&How-to\ links     :help how-to<CR>
an <silent> 9999.40 He&lp.&Find\.\.\.   :call <SID>Helpfind()<CR>
an 9999.45 He&lp.-sep1-         <Nop>
an 9999.50 He&lp.&Credits       :help credits<CR>
an 9999.60 He&lp.Co&pying       :help copying<CR>
an 9999.70 He&lp.&Sponsor/Register  :help sponsor<CR>
an 9999.70 He&lp.O&rphans       :help kcc<CR>
an 9999.75 He&lp.-sep2-         <Nop>
an 9999.80 He&lp.&Version       :version<CR>
an 9999.90 He&lp.&About         :intro<CR>
```

(Note that if you leave the `&` out entirely, it looks like the first character of the menu will be used instead, which puts you back in the same spot.)

Comment: thanks, but what I'm really looking for is a way to keep the menu, but override the accelerator mapping. After looking at menu.vim, i couldn't find where the accelerator was defined, and I don't want to remove it, as I am not confident enough in my vim-fu to do so safely.

Comment: @theresawalrus I thought as much, so I put together an example for you, it just took me a bit longer than the nuclear solution of removing the menu entirely. The accelerator is either the first character of the menu or the character after the '&'.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot more sense. I'll have to use something different than `l` though, otherwise it's the same problem all over again :)